# Saving and reverting revision history on a database record

Tags: mongodb, diff, wiki, database

I'm planning on building site that allows users to add, edit and delete records depending on their status, not that dissimilar from Stack Overflow. Any user should be able to edit records like a wiki, but to avoid sabotage all revisions must be saved so that we can revert back if need be.

I imagine there are several ways you could do this. How do sites like Wikipedia and Stack Overflow manage this type of data?

PS. I am using MongoDB for data persistence.

Answer (score 3):

You have two orthogonal choices.

#### Storage

1. Keep history in the very same document, in a field name `versions` (or whatever).
2. Save changes to a separate collection to keep the original document clean.

#### Format

1. Save original version verbatim. This facilitates rollbacks (just get prev version and overwrite current).
2. Store only modified fields, this will save you some space (be careful when adding/removing fields).

   2.1. To economize on space even further, you can store diffs of string values.